# How to subtract two times in Unix to get the completion time for autosys job

Tags: datetime, unix, autosys

I want to calculate completion time for an autosys job:

I have below job status in file:

```
$cat rough
abc_why_the_infra_dnjob               10/05/2017 10:41:36  10/05/2017 12:52:02  SU
abc_why_the_avloqhk_dnjob             10/05/2017 09:53:36  10/05/2017 10:33:03  SU
abc_why_the_avlogsg_dnjob             10/05/2017 10:33:14  10/05/2017 10:41:01  SU
abc_why_the_avalokin_dnjob            10/05/2017 09:37:36  10/05/2017 09:53:06  SU
abc_why_the_mastercard_dnjob          10/05/2017 13:29:36  10/05/2017 14:21:02  SU
abc_why_the_tcs_dnjob                 10/05/2017 03:13:36  10/05/2017 03:22:02  SU
abc_why_the_cogni_dnjob               10/05/2017 09:20:36  10/05/2017 09:37:02  SU
abc_why_the_dnjob                  10/05/2017 03:41:36  10/05/2017 04:08:02  SU
```

And I wrote the below script to calculate it:

---

```
$ cat sod.sh

#!/bin/bash

number=`cat rough| wc -l`

for i in `seq 1 $number`
do

        job_name=`awk -F' ' '{print $1}' rough | sed -n "$i p"`

        START_DATE=`awk -F' ' '{print $2}' rough | sed -n "$i p"`
        END_DATE=`awk -F' ' '{print $4}' rough | sed -n "$i p"`

        START_TIME=`awk -F' ' '{print $3}' rough | sed -n "$i p"`
        END_TIME=`awk -F' ' '{print $5}' rough | sed -n "$i p"`

        if [[ $START_DATE == $END_DATE ]]
        then
                T1=`date --date="${END_DATE} ${END_TIME}" "+%s"`
                T2=`date --date="${START_DATE} ${START_TIME}" "+%s"`

                TIME_DIFFERENCE=`expr $T2 - $T1`
                COMPLITION_TIME=`date -d "@${TIME_DIFFERENCE}" "+%H:%M:%S"`

                echo $COMPLITION_TIME
        fi
done
```

---

Output:

```
$./sod.sh
03:19:34
04:50:33
05:22:13
05:14:30
04:38:34
05:21:34
05:13:34
05:03:34
```

My Query now: The output is incorrect can you suggest me.
I am expecting correct answers like:
02:11  >>  for first job

Comment: Do you ever get jobs that start at say 23:04:59 on day1 and end at 00:34:31 on day2?  Your script is appallingly inefficient.  You could process the data with a single `awk` script.

Comment: No Jonathan, These jobs are starting from 6AM IST time and mostly completed before 6PM IST , and these jobs using the reuse file job ( previous day file ) so no chance of running long for 2 days combination.

Comment: @Jonathan, I am just curious to know how we can subtract time entity in unix beside the lengthy substation `expr $H2 - $H1` ,   `expr $M2 - $M1` , `expr $S2 - $S` and so on..

Comment: Like I showed you.  Convert the time to an offset in seconds from some reference time (midnight, or 'The Epoch' — 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00).  Then take the difference between those offsets, and format that as hours, minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer using a Python script:

```
>>> s1='10:41:36'
>>> s2='12:52:02'
>>> import datetime
>>> import time
>>> total_time=(datetime.datetime.strptime(s2,'%H:%M:%S') - datetime.datetime.strptime(s1,'%H:%M:%S'))
>>> print total_time
2:10:26
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have GNU Awk on the machine?  It's hard work if you don't — but easier (though not easy) if you do because it has support for time manipulation — see [time functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Time-Functions) in the manual.

The date format in the file doesn't help - it isn't even clear whether it is mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy format, though given that the question was asked on 2017-10-05, it is most likely mm/dd/yyyy.

This script using `gawk` (GNU Awk — you may be able to use just `awk`) does the job.  It uses two user-defined functions and `mktime()`.  It doesn't use `strftime()` because that works in local time which isn't correct for me and probably isn't correct for you (but it would otherwise be tempting to use `strtime("%H:%M:%S", t2 - t1)` to get the time value in hh:mm:ss units).

```
gawk '
function cvt_mdy_hms(d0, t0,    d1, t1, dt, rv){ #d0="10/05/2017"; t0="10:41:36";
    split(d0, d1, "/"); split(t0, t1, ":");
    dt = d1[3] " " d1[1] " " d1[2] " " t1[1] " " t1[2] " " t1[3];
    rv = mktime(dt);
    # print "[", dt, "] =", rv;
    return rv
}
function hms(secs,    hh, mm, ss, rv) {
    hh = int(secs / 3600);
    mm = int(secs / 60) % 60;
    ss = secs % 60;
    rv = sprintf("%.2d:%.2d:%.2d", hh, mm, ss);
    # print "[", secs, " = ", rv, "]";
    return rv;
}
NF == 6 { t1 = cvt_mdy_hms($2, $3); t2 = cvt_mdy_hms($4, $5);
  printf "%-30s  %2s  time %8s;  [%10s %8s] = %10d  [%10s %8s] = %10d; delta = %6d\n",
         $1, $6, hms(t2 - t1), $2, $3, t1, $4, $5, t2, t2 - t1;
}' data
```

Given your data file (in a file called `data`), the output is:

```
abc_why_the_infra_dnjob         SU  time 02:10:26;  [10/05/2017 10:41:36] = 1507225296  [10/05/2017 12:52:02] = 1507233122; delta =   7826
abc_why_the_avloqhk_dnjob       SU  time 00:39:27;  [10/05/2017 09:53:36] = 1507222416  [10/05/2017 10:33:03] = 1507224783; delta =   2367
abc_why_the_avlogsg_dnjob       SU  time 00:07:47;  [10/05/2017 10:33:14] = 1507224794  [10/05/2017 10:41:01] = 1507225261; delta =    467
abc_why_the_avalokin_dnjob      SU  time 00:15:30;  [10/05/2017 09:37:36] = 1507221456  [10/05/2017 09:53:06] = 1507222386; delta =    930
abc_why_the_mastercard_dnjob    SU  time 00:51:26;  [10/05/2017 13:29:36] = 1507235376  [10/05/2017 14:21:02] = 1507238462; delta =   3086
abc_why_the_tcs_dnjob           SU  time 00:08:26;  [10/05/2017 03:13:36] = 1507198416  [10/05/2017 03:22:02] = 1507198922; delta =    506
abc_why_the_cogni_dnjob         SU  time 00:16:26;  [10/05/2017 09:20:36] = 1507220436  [10/05/2017 09:37:02] = 1507221422; delta =    986
abc_why_the_dnjob               SU  time 00:26:26;  [10/05/2017 03:41:36] = 1507200096  [10/05/2017 04:08:02] = 1507201682; delta =   1586
```

It would also be possible to do the job in Perl without too much fuss, and in pure Python as well.